# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcMovie'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am currently trying to teach myself some .net core code.

I am currently following a tutorial on the Microsoft site.

when I try and build my code i get the following error:

> /Users/xxxx/dotnet/MvcMovie/Startup.cs(1,16): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcMovie' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/Users/xxxx/dotnet/MvcMovie/MvcMovie.csproj]

My Startup.cs file looks like this

```
using MvcMovie.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MvcMovie
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            
            services.AddDbContext<MvcMovieContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is where i have set up the namespace (Data/MvcMovieContext.cs)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Data
{
    public class MvcMovieContext : DbContext
    {
        public MvcMovieContext (DbContextOptions<MvcMovieContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have followed the tutorial the letter, i have checked file names and tried google.  Im not at a loss.

---Addition---
Image of project structure added.

Screenshot of the current project structure  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Ns6.png)

Comment: Do you have another project in your solution?

Comment: Not that i am aware, this is my first attempt at a .net core web application

How can i check?

Comment: How many projects your solution has?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, what is the definition of a project? and how can i check?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my project structure to the bottom of the question

Comment: Hi @GlennCoyle,any update? does my solution useful?

Comment: Hi @yinqiu - it sure does, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Data` folder should not be placed under `bin/debug/net5.0`, it should be at the same level as the `Controlles` under the project.

Like following:
[image]